# Gradle and Cmake failing to find cpp file that is definitely there

Tags: c++, gradle, cmake, ninja

I run gradle to build an android .aar and it reports that it can't find a file, but the file definitely is there.

```
$ ./gradlew.bat assembleRelease

> Task :webrtc-native:externalNativeBuildRelease FAILED
Build mrwebrtc arm64-v8a
ninja: error: 'C:/Developer/Microsoft-MRWebRTC/libs/mrwebrtc/src/interop/data_channel_interop.cpp', needed by 'CMakeFiles/mrwebrtc.dir/C_/Developer/Microsoft-MRWebRTC/libs/mrwebrtc/src/interop/data_channel_interop.cpp.o', missing and no known rule to make it

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':webrtc-native:externalNativeBuildRelease'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build C:\Developer\Microsoft-MRWebRTC\tools\build\android\webrtc-native\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\arm64-v8a --target mrwebrtc}
  ninja: error: 'C:/Developer/Microsoft-MRWebRTC/libs/mrwebrtc/src/interop/data_channel_interop.cpp', needed by 'CMakeFiles/mrwebrtc.dir/C_/Developer/Microsoft-MRWebRTC/libs/mrwebrtc/src/interop/data_channel_interop.cpp.o', missing and no known rule to make it
```

But the file `C:/Developer/Microsoft-MRWebRTC/libs/mrwebrtc/src/interop/data_channel_interop.cpp` is definitely there.

```
$ cd C:/Developer/Microsoft-MRWebRTC/libs/mrwebrtc/src/interop/

User MSYS /c/Developer/Microsoft-MRWebRTC/libs/mrwebrtc/src/interop (master)
$ ls
data_channel_interop.cpp                 global_factory.cpp  interop_api.cpp                local_video_track_interop.cpp  remote_audio_track_interop.cpp  transceiver_interop.cpp
external_video_track_source_interop.cpp  global_factory.h    local_audio_track_interop.cpp  peer_connection_interop.cpp    remote_video_track_interop.cpp
```

Could anyone help? I am kind of running out of ideas on this.

Comment: Looks like some mess with Windows paths (``\`` as a delimiter) and Unix paths (`/` as a delimiter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered it was because I had 'caseSensitive' flags enabled on some of my directories. Be careful, this is a new feature of WSL2 and there are some peculiarities where you may be enabled in without realizing. Windows cmake cannot traverse directories that have this flag enabled on them.

Read about it here:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/per-directory-case-sensitivity-and-wsl/